# Comparator for String List

Tags: java, string, list

I am brand new to Java :)

I have 2 String lists and I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to compare the two and have a resulting array which contains strings that are not in the other. For example, I have a list called oldStrings and one called Strings. I have seen the Comparator function but don't fully understand how it works, right now I was thinking I could create a for loop, loop through each string and then save that string:

```
for (final String str : oldStrings) {
  if(!strings.contains(str))
  {                     
    getLogger().info(str + " is not in strings list ");
  }
}
```

There's going to be up to 200 strings in this list. Would this be the best way to go about this? Thank you!

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such so we can respond appropriately.

Comment: It's not, its actually a module I'm writing for Wowza, the string list will contain different streams :)

Comment: @javamonkey79: The homework tag is now discouraged.

Comment: @Mark: I was not aware. Is there relevant discussion? TIA

Comment: @javamonkey79:  There's http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/.  But it is still kind of up in the air (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception) so take what I said with a grain of salt.  My point is that we shouldn't be compelling the OP to label it as homework, nor should we be doing it for them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Collection firstList = new ArrayList() {{
    add("str1");
    add("str2");
}};

Collection secondList = new ArrayList() {{
    add("str1");
    add("str3");
    add("str4");
}};


System.out.println("First List: " + firstList);
System.out.println("Second List: " + secondList);

// Here is main part
secondList.removeAll(firstList);

System.out.println("Result: " + secondList);
```

**Update:**
More sophisticated version of code

```
Collection<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
firstList.add("str1");
firstList.add("str2");

Collection<String> secondList = new ArrayList<String>();
secondList.add("str1");
secondList.add("str2");
secondList.add("str3");


System.out.println("First List: " + firstList);
System.out.println("Second List: " + secondList);

// Here is main part
secondList.removeAll(firstList);
```

**Update:**

To Get acctual difference between both String list go for this.

```
    Set<String> setOne = new HashSet<String>();        
    Set<String> setTwo = new HashSet<String>();
    setOne.add("1");
    setOne.add("2");
    setOne.add("5");
    setTwo.add("1");
    setTwo.add("3");
    setTwo.add("4");
    Set<String> setTwoDummy = new HashSet<String>(setTwo);
    setTwo.retainAll(setOne);        
    setTwoDummy.addAll(setOne);
    setTwoDummy.removeAll(setTwo);
    System.out.println(""+setTwoDummy);
```

Comment: Argh no, I hate this idiom (how you populate the lists)!  It subclasses ArrayList, adding new concrete classes to your class-base that have to be loaded separately by the classloader, just to save a few characters.  I know it's not pertitent to what you're actually trying to show, so I didn't d/v, but it is really bad practice IMO, and shouldn't be shown to the vulnerable :-).

Comment: Unless I am missing the point of the question, wouldn't this solution fail to print 'str2' which is not in secondList? I thought the idea was to get difference between the 2 - which would be: 'str2', 'str3', 'str4'

Comment: @Mark: In the case of ArrayList I definitely agree with you since you can always populate with Arrays.asList( ... ) in the constructor.

Comment: @javamonkey79: I think that idiom can be used for pretty much any collection, correct?  Except a `Map`?

Comment: @Mark: That is what I was kinda getting at - the only time I use the approach above is with maps as they have no easy way (that I know of) to construct them with elements.

Comment: @org.life.java: Did you see my question above? Wouldn't this solution fail to list items that are in the first, but not the second?

Comment: @javamonkey79 OP isn't looking for that , wait your answer is on way..don't downvote atleast

Comment: @javamonkey79 here is your answer.

Answer (score 4):

First, the problem with your solution is that it will only find elements that are in `oldStrings` and not `strings`. If you're going with this approach then you need to loop on the other list as well.

If this is not for homework then check out CollectionUtils.disjunction from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29).

Answer (score 1):

> Compare two lists of strings and have a
>   resulting array which contains strings
>   that are not in the other.

The description is ambiguous because we don't we don't know if we need just non matching strings from the first list, the second list, or both.  Below is pseudo code for both.

```
for (String str : oldStrings)
{
  if(strings.contains(str))
  {
    intersectionList.add(str);
  }
}

oldStrings.removeAll(intersectionList);
strings.removeAll(intersectionList);
result = strings.addAll(oldStrings).toArray();
```

Or

```
copyStrings = strings.clone();
strings.removeAll(oldStrings);
oldStrings.removeAll(copyStrings);
result = strings.addAll(oldStrings).toArray();
```

Comment: You don't need the intersection list.  Just do `oldStrings.removeAll(strings)` and `strings.removeAll(oldStrings)` and then add one to the other.  All you're doing by using the `intersectionList` is making sure that nothing that isn't in oldStrings is removed from oldStrings...which can't happen anyway.

Comment: old = [1,2,3,4,5], current = [3,4,5,6], old.removeAll(current) => old =[1,2], current.removeAll(old) => current = [3,4,5,6].  Is this not correct?

Comment: Whoops I'm sorry, yes you're absolutely right.  I should have said it doesn't matter whether intersectionList actually contains the intersection or in this case just contains a copy of oldStrings (`oldStrings.removeAll(strings); strings.removeAll(oldStringsCopy)`).  If you're going to go to the trouble of manually building a list, why not reverse the logic and build the disjunction directly?  (`if ( !strings.contains(str) ) { disjunct.add(str); }`)

Comment: Disjunction doesn't seem as clear, but it does seem faster (one less removeAll).  You'll still have to disjunct.add(strings.removeAll(oldStrings)).

Comment: I was thinking more of two loops, the second one swapping the role of `strings` and `oldStrings`.  That way no removeAll is required.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Google Guava's [`Sets`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) utilities.

```
Set<String> s = Sets.newHashSet("a", "b", "c", "d");
Set<String> t = Sets.newHashSet("f", "g", "a", "c");
Sets.SetView<String> difference = Sets.difference(s, t);
System.out.println(difference); // prints [b, d]
```