# comparing 2 files using java

Tags: java, text

i have 2 text files, file_1: and the other file2

```
file_1:

tango 12
beta 256
alpha 1700
tango 1200

file_2:

tango 12
tango 125 hello world
beta 256
alpha 1700
```

i need to remove lines in file_2 which contains file_1 entries.
ie. read line by line from file_2, compare with file_1 lines, if match , remove , else append to a new file. matches are exact string matches, both are text files.
can any one tell me how can i do it using java

Comment: Good luck with your homework.

Answer (score 4):

Break the problem into steps:

1. [Read a file](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/ReadLinesFromFile.html) into a [list](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_Lists.html) of strings
2. [Iterate](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_Iterate.html) over two collections of strings and compare them
3. [Write to a file](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/WriteToFile.html)

Answer (score 1):

Read both file in to Collection of String.

Then compare two List  and process accordingly.

Rest all things are given by duffymo , [Here is how to compare two arraylist of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217740/4217770#4217770)